# Why do decimal values show up as "0"?

Tags: ruby, hash, floating-point, key-value

I'm using this code to populate values in a nested hash structure:

```
metrics_hash = Hash[ @metrics_array.map {|key| [key, nil] }]
demos_hash = Hash[@demos_types_array.map {|key| [key, metrics_hash] } ]

demos_hash.each do |demo , metric_hash |
    metric_hash.each do |metric , value |
        demo_index = @demos_types_array.index(demo)
        metric_index = @metrics_array.index(metric)
        offset = @demos_types_array.length() 
        value_index = metric_index * offset + demo_index 
        val = @demo_vals[value_index]
        metric_hash[metric] = val

    end
   puts "#{demo.inspect} => #{metric_hash.inspect} "
end
row_hash = row_hash.merge!({"demos" => demos_hash } )
end
```

(To make the above code more readable I removed some print statements.)

When I print `row_hash`, the `val` values in `demos_hash`  that were decimal numbers, show up as `"0"`:

```
demos"=>{"Ind.2+"=>{"AMA(000)"=>"0", "Shr% [Total TV Eng]"=>"0", "#Stations"=>"25"}, 
"A18+"=>{"AMA(000)"=>"0", "Shr% [Total TV Eng]"=>"0", "#Stations"=>"25"}, 
"A25-54"=> {"AMA(000)"=>"0", "Shr% [Total TV Eng]"=>"0", "#Stations"=>"25"}, 
"A18-49"=> {"AMA(000)"=>"0", "Shr% [Total TV Eng]"=>"0", "#Stations"=>"25"}, 
"A18-34"=> {"AMA(000)"=>"0", "Shr% [Total TV Eng]"=>"0", "#Stations"=>"25"}, 
"A55+"=> {"AMA(000)"=>"0", "Shr% [Total TV Eng]"=>"0", "#Stations"=>"25"}, 
"F25-54"=> {"AMA(000)"=>"0", "Shr% [Total TV Eng]"=>"0", "#Stations"=>"25"}, 
...........
"C2-11"=> {"AMA(000)"=>"0", "Shr% [Total TV Eng]"=>"0", "#Stations"=>"25"}}}
```

Most of the `"0"` values above were decimals that were somehow converted to `"0"`. Notice that the value of stations is untouched. The above values were inserted from this array:

```
 demo_values = ["5.1", "5.1", "3.3", "3", "2.5", "1.9", "0", "0", "0", "3.3", "3",      
 "2.5", "2.5", "0", "0", "0.6", "0.6", "0.7", "0.6", "1.1", "0.7", "0", "0", "0", "1.4", 
 "1.2", "2.2", "0.9", "0", "0", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", 
 "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25"]
```

Note the output of this line:

```
  puts "#{demo.inspect} => #{metric_hash.inspect} "
```

of code comes out as follows:

```
  "A18-34" => {"AMA(000)"=>"2.5", "Shr% [Total TV Eng]"=>"1.1", "#Stations"=>"25"}
```

As you can see, most of the numbers in the array are decimals.

And the program is populating the `metrics_hash` correctly. The problem happens when I print the entire `row_hash` which contains the `demos_hash` above. What could possibly be happening?

I checked the class of all the variables and tried to cast the numbers but no luck, I cannot seem to make headway.

Can someone kindly help me understand how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're overlooking the real problem: every value in `demos_hash` is exactly the same object. So, if you change one of the values, you're actually changing them all. When you do this:

```
demos_hash = Hash[@demos_types_array.map {|key| [key, metrics_hash] } ]
```

You're not making any copies of `metrics_hash`, you're just assigning the same reference to every value of `demos_hash`. I suspect that you just need to make copies:

```
demos_hash = Hash[@demos_types_array.map {|key| [key, metrics_hash.dup] } ]
# ----------------------------------------------------------------^^^^
```

That will give you distinct Hashes in your `demos_hash` values and things should start making more sense.